# What happens if there is no fallback function in solidity?

Tags: solidity, fallback-function

Here is the short definition about [fallback function](https://www.bitdegree.org/learn/solidity-functions#fallback) in solidity:

```
Solidity fallback function does not have any arguments, has external visibility and does not return anything.
```

What happens if there is no fallback function and someone calls non-existing function in the smart contract? Is there security complication without a fallback function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call will simple fail and revert. There are no security implications as everything will be reverted.

Comment: May the contract not collect some ether associated with the call?

Comment: No. The whole transaction reverts. All possible Ethers are returned.

Comment: @LauriPeltonen what happens if there is fallback function then? It wont cause an error even though the function doesnt exist?

Comment: Sorry but the questions doesn't make sense. Either it exists or it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, the call will fail and revert but there are exceptions.
A contract could self-destruct and forcefully send ether to another contract, even if that contract is missing a fallback function.
This could cause security implications resulting in unexpected behavior whenever it checks `address(this).balance`.

In the following example, sending 1 ETH would end voting prematurely:

```js
contract Election {
    uint public yesVotes;
    uint public noVotes;

    // stop after 100 votes
    function vote(bool _forOrAgainst) public payable {
        // Each voter pays 0.01 ETH
        require(msg.value == 1e16, "Please send exactly 0.01 ETH");

        // A hacker could end voting before 100 votes by sending ether so
        // that the contract's balance >= 1 ether
        require(address(this).balance < 1e18, "Voting has closed");
        _forOrAgainst ? yesVotes++ : noVotes++;
    }
}
```

**Warning**: Spoiler ahead for those who are attempting [Ethernaut](https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/) as it is the solution to one of the levels.

Calling the code below would allow you to send ether to a contract without a fallback function. It can be used against the contract above to stop the voting process prematurely.

> ```
>  contract Attack {
>      function attack(address payable addr) public payable {
>          selfdestruct(addr);
>      }
>  }
> ```

[This article](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-hack-smart-contracts-self-destruct-and-solidity) also gives another example of how to hack a contract using `selfdestruct`.